# How to make a image that has clickable details and more

Tags: jquery, image, html

I want put a image that contains details like house and etc on the web, it should be able to click on the them inside the image and also possible to go left and right and zoom in on the picture.

Is there any good code demos possibly with jquery or php anyone could recommend me to visit and see?

Comment: you want to make your maps? code demo: maps.google.com

Comment: its a image with a bunch of house on it, that should be clickable that takes you to another url something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're after an image map, maybe?  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

```
<img src="neighborhood.jpg" width="145" height="126" alt="Neighborhood" usemap="#neighborhoodmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="house1.html" alt="House1">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="house2.html" alt="Round House1">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="house3.html" alt="Round House2">
</map>
```

**UPDATE ---**
Here's also a jquery plugin I found for panning and zooming an image.  Not sure if it'll break the image map or not though:
http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/pan-zoom/

Seem to be plenty more of them if you do a Google search for "jquery pan zoom image" or similar

Comment: Yeah but about the zoom in and going left or right on the image is that some kind of jquery that I add on the image?

Comment: Yeah, there very well could be some jQuery or a jQuery plugin that could accomplish that for you.

Comment: Thank you will accept it when timer is gone  :)

Comment: Just added an update to my answer above.  Found a jquery plugin as an example for panning and zooming an image.